# How to add several parameters in qiskit circuit?

Tags: qiskit, programming, vqe

I want to construct an ansatz circuit in Qiskit, so I need some parameters to act on the gates (e.g. RX(a), RY(b)). In the Qiskit tutorials I find a way to implement a parameter:

```
import numpy as np

theta_range = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 128)
circuits = [qc.bind_parameters({theta: theta_val})
            for theta_val in theta_range]
circuits[-1].draw()
```

There is only one parameter, `theta`. I want more parameters in the some range. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Thanks for asking a question! Could you add the definition of the `qc` variable?

Answer (score 6):

You can create an arbitrary number of parameters in your circuit by using the `qiskit.circuit.Parameter` class. Here's a brief example

```
from qiskit.circuit import Parameter, QuantumCircuit

# define your parameters
a, b, c = Parameter('a'), Parameter('b'), Parameter('c')

circuit = QuantumCircuit(2)
circuit.rx(a, 0)  # RX(a) on qubit 0
circuit.ry(b, 0)  # RY(b) on qubit 1
circuit.crz(c, 0, 1)  # CRZ(c) controlled on qubit 0, acting on qubit 1

# bind the values
bound_circuit = circuit.bind_parameters({a: 0, b: 1, c: 2})

# or if you have a list of values
a_vals = [0, 1, 2, 3]
b_vals = [1, 2, 3, 4]
c_vals = [2, 3, 4, 5]
bound_circuits = [circuit.bind_parameters(
    {a: a_val, b: b_val, c: c_val}) 
     for (a_val, b_val, c_val) in zip(a_vals, b_vals, c_vals)]
```

For convenience there's also the `ParameterVector` class to construct multiple parameters at once. The above example can also look like

```
from qiskit.circuit import ParameterVector, QuantumCircuit

# define your parameters
p = ParameterVector('p', 3)  

circuit = QuantumCircuit(2)
circuit.rx(p[0], 0)  # RX(p[0]) on qubit 0
circuit.ry(p[1], 0)  # RY(p[1]) on qubit 1
circuit.crz(p[2], 0, 1)  # CRZ(p[2]) controlled on qubit 0, acting on qubit 1

# bind the values
bound_circuit = circuit.bind_parameters({p: [0, 1, 2]})

# or for a list of values
values = [ [0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4] ]
bounds_circuits = [circuit.bind_parameters({p: val for val in values})
```

Comment: oh! thank you. i

Comment: Thank you. but there's something wrong with your code.

Comment: bound_circuits = [circuit.bind_parameters(
    {a: a_val, b: b_val, c: c_val for 
     (a_val, b_val, c_val) in zip(a_vals, b_vals, c_vals)}
)]  There seems to be something wrong with this code. The error as follows:  File "<ipython-input-4-78b6b27b9d79>", line 14
    {a: a_val, b: b_val, c: c_val for    (SyntaxError: invalid syntax)

Comment: and in the bound_circuit = circuit.bind_parameters({p: [0, 1, 2]}). How can I define a value range for these three parameters?

Comment: Can you correct it?@Cryoris

Comment: oh yeah the brackets were off, its corrected

Comment: I also added an example for multiple values and the parameter vector

Comment: it seems like that you know qiskit well. can I friend you in facebook or twitter or something?@Cryoris

Comment: Ah, just a little bit! You can join the Slack community, there's many people that know Qiskit very well: https://ibm.co/joinqiskitslack.

Comment: ok. thank you. I have seen your notebook about VQE. but i still have some question. 
 The following: h2_hamiltonian = -1.05 * (I ^ I) + 0.39 * (I ^ Z) - 0.39 * (Z ^ I) - 0.01 * (Z ^ Z) + 0.18 * (X ^ X). Is there any way that the operator can act on a specific qubit? Just like: X3 Indicates that X acts on the third qubit. @Cryoris

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112601/discussion-between-wu-peter-and-cryoris).

Comment: You should consider accepting this answer.